# attempting to write with unique constraint or handle from script

Tags: mysql

I created a script that is taking data from an outside source and writing it into a mysql database. Which would you recommend for preventing duplicates from ending up in the database?

One option I can think of is to enable the unique constraint so that a duplicate value is not stored, but if the script attempts to write the value to the database, then the database has to spend some time determining if the value already exists. The other option I thought of is to initialize a list or set of data from the database each time the script runs and before the script attempts to write to the database, it can cross reference if the value exists in the list that was initialized at the start. From a performance standard, what makes the most sense? Is there something I didn't consider?

Comment: How many inserts/second?  If more than 1000, we can discuss further.  Otherwise, just do what is simpler for you.  See also IODKU.

Answer (score 0):

A unique or primary key on a column will prevent duplicate keys in the table existing.

The finding of an existing key is not a wasted effort, it corresponds to where in the underlying data row needs to be inserted.

If the value of that is unique isn't important there is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute that can be used on `INT` columns.

Solve performance problems when you see them rather than prematurely.